# How to use function rclcpp_action::create_server in class with ROS2 Crystal?

Tags: ros2, actionlib, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I am trying to **make a class with actionlib** in **ROS2 crystal.** I started by modifying the example code [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/minimal_action_server/not_composable.cpp).

However, I get stuck in calling the function **rclcpp_action::create_server**. Is there any example for write a actionlib sever in class with ROS2 crystal??? Thank you!!!

here is the error I get

```
/home/q600/rclcpp_ws/src/universal_actionlib/src/universal_actionlib_server.cpp: In member function ‘void UniversalActionlibServer::init()’:
/home/q600/rclcpp_ws/src/universal_actionlib/src/universal_actionlib_server.cpp:19:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘create_server<StringTask>(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::_Bind_helper<false, rclcpp_action::GoalResponse (UniversalActionlibServer::*)(std::array<unsigned char, 16>&, std::shared_ptr<universal_actionlib_interface::action::StringTask_Goal_Request_<std::allocator<void> > >), UniversalActionlibServer*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type, std::_Bind_helper<false, rclcpp_action::CancelResponse (UniversalActionlibServer::*)(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<universal_actionlib_interface::action::StringTask> >), UniversalActionlibServer*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type, std::_Bind_helper<false, void (UniversalActionlibServer::*)(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<universal_actionlib_interface::action::StringTask> >), UniversalActionlibServer*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)’
     );
     ^
In file included from /opt/ros/crystal/include/rclcpp_action/rclcpp_action.hpp:34:0,
                 from /home/q600/rclcpp_ws/src/universal_actionlib/include/universal_actionlib/universal_actionlib_server.hpp:4,
                 from /home/q600/rclcpp_ws/src/universal_actionlib/src/universal_actionlib_server.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/crystal/include/rclcpp_action/create_server.hpp:36:1: note: candidate: template<class ActionT> typename rclcpp_action::Server<ActionT>::SharedPtr rclcpp_action::create_server(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr, const string&, typename rclcpp_action::Server<ActionT>::GoalCallback, typename rclcpp_action::Server<ActionT>::CancelCallback, typename rclcpp_action::Server<ActionT>::AcceptedCallback, const rcl_action_server_options_t&, rclcpp::callback_group::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr)
 create_server(
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also check the code [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/master/rclcpp_action/test/test_server.cpp). But I still didn't get it how to use actionlib in class.

Here is my code:

StringTask.action

```
# Goal
string task_s
---
# Result
string result_s
---
# Feedback
string feedback_s
```

actionlib_server_class.hpp

```
#ifndef UNIVERSAL_ACTIONLIB_SERVER_H
#define UNIVERSAL_ACTIONLIB_SERVER_H
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_action/rclcpp_action.hpp"
#include "universal_actionlib_interface/action/string_task.hpp"
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include "functional"

using namespace std;
using StringTask = universal_actionlib_interface::action::StringTask;
using GoalHandleStringTask = rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<StringTask>;
using GoalID = rclcpp_action::GoalID;

class UniversalActionlibServer
{
public:
    UniversalActionlibServer(string action_name);
    ~UniversalActionlibServer(){};

    void init();

private:
    rclcpp_action::GoalResponse handle_goal(GoalID &uuid, shared_ptr<StringTask::Goal> goal);
    rclcpp_action::CancelResponse handle_cancel(shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle);
    void handle_accepted(shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle);
    void execute(const shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle);

    string action_name_;
    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;
};
```

actionlib_server.cpp

```
#include "universal_actionlib/universal_actionlib_server.hpp"

UniversalActionlibServer::UniversalActionlibServer(string action_name)
{
    action_name_ = action_name;
    node_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared(action_name_);
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("server"),"Establishing the action server %s...",action_name_);
}

void UniversalActionlibServer::init()
{
    auto action_server = rclcpp_action::create_server<StringTask>(
        node_,
        action_name_,
        std::bind(&UniversalActionlibServer::handle_goal, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2),
        std::bind(&UniversalActionlibServer::handle_cancel, this, std::placeholders::_1),
        std::bind(&UniversalActionlibServer::handle_accepted, this, std::placeholders::_1)
    );
}

rclcpp_action::GoalResponse UniversalActionlibServer::handle_goal(GoalID &uuid, shared_ptr<StringTask::Goal> goal)
{
    return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE;
}

rclcpp_action::CancelResponse UniversalActionlibServer::handle_cancel(shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("server"), "Got request to cancel goal");
    (void)goal_handle;
    return rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT;
}

void UniversalActionlibServer::handle_accepted(shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle)
{
    std::thread{&UniversalActionlibServer::execute, this, goal_handle}.detach();
}

void UniversalActionlibServer::execute(const shared_ptr<GoalHandleStringTask> goal_handle)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("server"), "Executing goal");
    rclcpp::Rate loop_rate(1);
    const auto goal = goal_handle->get_goal();
    auto _feedback = std::make_shared<StringTask::Feedback>();
    auto _result = std::make_shared<StringTask::Result>();

    // Storage the result from do_something
    string tmp_goal;
    string tmp_feedback;
    string tmp_result;

    tmp_goal = goal->task_s;

    while( do_something())
    {
        _feedback->feedback_s = tmp_feedback;
        goal_handle->publish_feedback(_feedback);
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("server"), "Publish Feedback");

        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    _result->result_s = tmp_result;
    goal_handle->set_succeeded(_result);
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("server"), "Goal Suceeded");
}
#endif // UNIVERSAL_ACTIONLIB_SERVER_H
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315909/how-to-use-function-rclcpp_action::create_server-in-class-with-ros2-crystal?/) by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the signature of the `handle_goal` function isn't quite right. Try making the template type `const`:

```
rclcpp_action::GoalResponse handle_goal(GoalID &uuid, shared_ptr<const StringTask::Goal> goal);
```

For future reference, I've opened a PR adding examples that use member functions:

https://github.com/ros2/examples/pull/230/files

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on 2019-03-13**:
You're right! It works on me! Thank you~